# MDX get data from multiple dimensions without measure

Tags: ssms, mdx, olap, olap-cube, azure-analysis-services

I have an OLAP cube with many dimensions. I am trying to retrieve related data from two of them. The problem is that this cube does not have any measures, so I'm not sure how to work with it. As a side note, I am completely new to OLAP cubes and MDX.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
{} ON 0, 
CROSSJOIN (
[Entity].[EntityPRID].&[1234],
[Entity].[EntityName].[EntityName].MEMBERS,
[Entity-Parent].[EntityParentPRID].[EntityParentPRID].MEMBERS
)
ON 1
FROM[Model]
```

However I get rows with all the possible Entity-Parent PRIDs instead of just the one for the Entity with PRID 1234. I tried adding NON EMPTY as well as NonEmptyCrossJoin, however in both cases I get 0 results.

My expected result would be:

```
1234 | SomeName | 4321
```

and what I get now is:

```
1234 | SomeName | 4000
1234 | SomeName | 4001
1234 | SomeName | 4002
1234 | SomeName | 4003
1234 | SomeName | 4004
1234 | SomeName | 4005
1234 | SomeName | 4006
...
```

If it would be possible to somehow include the column names in the output, that would be ideal as well, as in the end I need to use the query in my C# app and put the data into a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try wrapping the EXISTING function around this bit:

```
EXISTING(
  [Entity-Parent].[EntityParentPRID].[EntityParentPRID].MEMBERS)
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes

Comment: Strange to have a cube with no measures?